# заменить часть содержимого в переменной jquery на другую переменную

Tags: jquery

Мне необходимо в переменной заменить часть html-кода, равную другой переменной. Как это можно сделать?

Есть такой код (сильно мной измученный, вероятно):

```
if ($(this).data('clicked')) { // если не первый клик на эту строку tr
    var form_trs = document.getElementById('rez').html;
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr").get(0).outerHTML;
    var rezult = form_trs.replace(tr,"");
    document.getElementById('rez').html(rezult);
 }
```

И мне необходимо в блоке кода условия удалить в значении переменной var form_trs все вхождения значения переменной var tr.

Моя попытка сделать так: `var rezult = form_trs.replace(tr,"");`  результатов не принесла.
А как тут использовать .replaceWith я что-то не могу никак сообразить.

Буду очень благодарна за помощь.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` - функция, которая возвращает jQuery-объект с полезными методами. `.html()` — метод jQuery (который нужно вызывать, со скобками), он не будет работать для `document.getElementById('rez')`. Но т.к. вы не вызвали() метод, а только указали его имя, `document.getElementById('rez').html` не выдал ошибку, а молча вернул `undefined`, который попал в переменную `form_trs`.

А replace в вашем случае заменяет только первое совпадение. Чтобы заменить всё, ему нужен флажок `"g"` - global.

```
var form_trs = $('#rez').html();
var tr = $(this).closest("tr").get(0).outerHTML;

var reg = new RegExp( tr, "g" );
var result = form_trs.replace( reg, "" );

$('#rez').html(result);
```

P.s. `$("#rez").html() ←→ document.getElementById("rez").innerHtml`

---

Но, `<tr></tr>` и `<tr> /перенос строки/ </tr>` — это не одно и то же. Если HTML добавляется динамически, скриптом, и везде с одинаковыми пробелами / переносами строк, replace сойдет. Но было бы грамотнее найти другую общую деталь для этих tr (класс / содержимое их ячеек?) и фильтровать таблицу по этим показателям.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо! А tr в данном случае добавляется скриптом из таблицы прайса в форму заявки. И данный фрагмент кода необходим для того, чтобы именно и конкретно эту (одну) строку удалить, если юзер решит, что погорячился. Еще раз благодарю!!!

Comment: @Наталья `$(this).closest("tr").remove()` ?) replace + вставка всего HTML обратно - заново рисует все элементы.